# Night light is not working on joined display on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, redshift, night-light

I was facing the problem of the night light not working on my laptop since I installed Ubuntu `20.04` but it gets resolved as soon as I restart my system. But now, when I started my system, the night light is working on the laptop screen but not on the joined display monitor, which was working fine since the time I am using joined displays which is more than 3 years.

Also, many people are facing this nightlight problem on their Ubuntu `20.04` and the only solution people are offering is rebooting the system, which solves the problem in many cases But rebooting the system every time I open it doesn't seem like a feasible solution. So is there any permanent solution to this problem?

Comment: You mention *night light* (which is part of GNOME), but also mention RedShift (a different program).  They can *fight* or interfere with each other and you get problems if you use two such programs that do the same thing. If you're using `redshift` as well as GNOME's night light; I'd suggest using just one.  Me I disabled GNOME's *night light* and just use `redshift`, as I have other desktops installed, and `redshift` works in all of them

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for your reply. Okay yes, I am only using night light. So you are suggesting that I should ask this question in the GNOME community right?  I will do that surely. thanks.

Comment: No, I was just talking from my experience of running two programs (GNOME's night light & `redshift`) at the same time. They can interfere with each other & the result isn't great.  As you mentioned the two programs I've used together, I was suggesting just using GNOME's *night light* alone, or `redshift` (with *night light* disabled). GNOME's Night light & `redshift` are different programs that do *almost* the same thing.  If you're using only one, I'd suggest correcting your question (you can edit your own questions) as it leads to my obvious response

Comment: It happened to me too. I have it set to manual timing, from 05:00 to 04:59. When it broke, even the nightlight icon did not show up in the panel. But I noticed that my monitors (laptop + external HDMI) have disappeared from the _Settings_ app's _Color_ settings sidebar item. I set the preinstalled `D50` color profile for my laptop's screen on that _Color_ settings UI. But now only my printer had shown up to set a color profile to: the monitors did not. I think it's related. A reboot however restored everything: the _Color_ settings UI, the laptop screen color profile, and night light.